# WriteToBigQuery is not loading data into BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm reading data from MySQL on Cloud SQL and writing into Bigquery using Dataflow. I'm trying with a simple code first but even that is not working!

```
class ReadFromJdbc(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, context):

        # Connection setup
        connection = jaydebeapi.connect(
            'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver',
            jdbc_url,
            [username, password],
            '/temp/mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar',  # Provide the path to the MySQL JDBC driver JAR
        )
        
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql) # 'select col1,col2 from mysql_table';

        while True:
            rows = cursor.fetchmany(1000)  
            if not rows:
                break

        for row in rows:
            # Convert Java types to Python types
            processed_row = tuple(int(value) if isinstance(value, java.lang.Integer) else value for value in row)
            yield processed_row

        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
```

the above two methods - Read from MySQL and WriteToBigQuery.
Various ways to convert MySql data to JSON for BigQuery -

> sql = select JSON_OBJECT('col1', col1,'col2', col2) as payload from
> employee
> [('{"col1": "100", "col2": "ABC"}',), ('{"col1":  "200",
> "col2": "DEF"}',), ('{"col1": "300", "col2": "GHI"}',)]

Another way to convert data into JSON for BQ write

> rows = cursor.fetchmany(1000) json_data=[] for rv in rows:
> json_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers,rv)))
>
> [{'col1': '100', 'col2': 'ABC'}, {'col1': '200', 'col2': 'DEF'}, {'col1': '300', 'col2': 'GHI'}]

Both the above formats fails to write into BQ

The code gets succeeded when I run the pipeline but nothing gets loaded into BigQuery table.

Pipeline options -

```
    table_spec = "my_project:my_dataset.my_table"    

    p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
    data = p | 'CreatePartitions' >> beam.Create(['1'])
    # Apply the pipeline steps using ParDo
    mysql_data = (
        data     
        | 'Read From Jdbc' >> beam.ParDo(ReadFromJdbc())
        | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            table_spec,
            schema='col1:INTEGER,col2:STRING',
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
       
    )

    mysql_data = p.run()
    mysql_data.wait_until_finish()


if __name__ == "__main__":    
    run()
```

Comment: Hi @dips, Are you getting any kind of error message ?

Comment: No @DhirajSingh, I'm not getting any error messages. The logs didn't contain "processed_row" information, even though I was trying to log it as INFO, as if the pipeline never reached there.

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Comment: Hi @DhirajSingh, I changed my code a little bit. Instead of WriteToBigQuery as a Dofn, I'm using the one available in beam.io. And I can see that from MySQL the data is read in the format - 
[["100", "ABC"], ["200", "DEF"], ["300", "GHI"]] 
but while loading into BQ I'm getting error as - Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up.

Comment: Hi All, I've understood the issue, it is due to incorrect format. BigQuery expects rows in {"col1": "100", "col2": "ABC"}. I've tried various methods to convert the MySQL result set to JSON but nothing is working. I've updated my original question to show that.